# Automated Actions in odoo 12. Set values with python code

Tags: python, odoo

I tried to take text from one field and set it modificated to another throught Execute Python Code.

```
recs = record.smt
for rec in recs:
    details = pythonwhois.get_whois(rec)
    if 'No match for' in str(details):
        record.smt2='ok'
    else:
        record.smt2='denied'
```

Error: forbidden opcode

Please, help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the line:

```
details = pythonwhois.get_whois(rec)
```

You are using a external library `pythonwhois` which is not imported, how do you suppose to use that in your execution. As `import` statement is also not allowed, you can't just import any library.

instead of using dot operator, try to use `write` function.

```
    if 'No match for' in str(details):
        smt2='ok'
    else:
        smt2='denied'
record.write({'smt2': smt})
```

Also keep in mind that `record` is the record on which the action is triggered; may be void

Comment: do you have access to add custom module?

Comment: you have to write functions in custom modules model definition, for that you need permission/access to add new modules.

Comment: thanks! where can i read more about actions? docs or book. i can't found information

Comment: You have to have knowledge of odoo Model, View and ORM concepts, you can follow documentation https://www.odoo.com/documentation/11.0/howtos/backend.html#build-an-odoo-module.